# Setar imagem usando banco Firebase

Tags: java, android

Preciso que a imagem que está guardada no *Storage Firebase* apareça na *listview* customizada. No entanto não consigo definir a imagem no formato `gs://<Seu banco><childs>`.

Já tentei utilizar o *Picasso* e o *Glide*, mas ambos precisam da URL da imagem, ou seja: `http://..`. E não consigo pegar essa URL.

O código é esse: https://github.com/VitorSantos1996/LivrariaFireBase

Se tiver como definir no formato `gs://..` ficará mais fácil.

Comment: Já tentou https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=pt-br#download_data_via_url ?

Comment: Ja sim, mas não consegui fazer, o meu getUid ta retornando null não sei porque.